# How can I sort my JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to output this JSON element in correct order by it's value?

```
var json = { 
    "message": {
        "90": "Adidas", 
        "2": "Armani", 
        "89": "Casio", 
        "1": "Diesel", 
        "72": "DKNY", 
        "88": "Fossil", 
        "4": "Hamilton", 
        "6": "Luminox", 
        "99": "Michael Kors", 
        "968": "Mont Blanc Pens", 
        "3": "Nixon", 
        "959": "Nooka", 
        "92": "Seiko", 
        "91": "Tendence", 
        "7": "Tissot" 
    } 
};

var str = '';
for (var i in json.message) {
    str += json.message[i]+'\n';
}
alert(str);
```

**it alerts in the below order -**

> Diesel
>       Armani
>       Nixon
>       Hamilton
>       Luminox
>       DKNY
>       Fossil
>       Casio
>       Adidas
>       Tendence
>       Seiko
>       Michael Kors
>       Nooka
>       Mont Blanc Pens

***But I want it in below order***

> Adidas
>       Armani
>       Casio
>       Diesel
>       DKNY
>       Fossil
>       Hamilton
>       Luminox
>       Michael Kors
>       Mont Blanc Pens
>       Nixon
>       Nooka
>       Seiko
>       Tendence
>       Tissot

Can any one suggest me what approach I should adopt to get in correct order?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Objects (not array, it's only PHP that uses things like associative arrays), do not have their keys in any order, although most JS VM's do preserve the order they were added in. But, since this can not be relied on, you need to generate an array of the values only, and then simply sort this (as other answers shows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want the elements listed in alphabetical order by their value:

```
var values = [];
for(var i in json.message) {
   values.push(json.message[i]);
}
var str = values.sort().join('\n');
```

**Update**

To form an array of key-value pairs ordered by their (string) value:

```
var values = [];
for(var i in json.message) {
   values.push({ key: i, value: json.message[i] });
}
values.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value.localeCompare(b.value); });
var str = values.map(function (kvp) { return kvp.value; }).join('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rich.okelly :) I was considering to sort the json object but your suggestion also works.

Comment: can key of the sorted array be preserved?

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = object.message;
var brands = Object.keys(message)
               .map(function(key) { return message[key]; })
               .sort();

alert(brands.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a leading 0 to each index. For example:

```
var json = { 
    "message": {
        "090": "Adidas", 
        "02": "Armani", 
        "089": "Casio", 
        "01": "Diesel", 
        ...
```

Comment: OP wants it in alphabetic order by _value,_ not by _index_ (key). But even if they were talking about sorting by index, how does adding leading zeros to _all_ indexes help?

Comment: When looping through associate arrays some browsers does not return keys in added order. 

http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: I know. But why do you think adding leading zeros will help?

Comment: Basically this is a work around for this issue. Please test this on IE and see.

Answer (score 0):

using JS library undescore.js is pretty easy, just do:

```
json.message=_.sortBy(json.message,function(i){return i;})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by this way, this is a sort basied on values :

```
function sortJsonMap(data){

var values = [];
var keys = [];

for(var i in data) {
   keys.push(i);
   values.push(data[i]);                     
}
values.sort();  
var map = new Object();
for(var i in values) {
     map[keys[i]]=values[i];
}
return map;
```

}